# Compile plugins for Uwsgi

Tags: python, plugins, uwsgi

I compile the uwsgi version x.y.zz.ww from the oficial site, i compiled the uwsgi with the command suggested from the official documentation

And then I compiled the plugins suggested for Python with the commands in the official documentation, the error output I get is this:

```
>ubuntu@ip-xx-yy-zz-ww:~/tmp/uwsgi-xx.yy.zz.ww$ PYTHON=python3.4 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python34"
*** uWSGI building and linking plugin from plugins/python ***
[gcc -pthread] python34_plugin.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m/libpython3.4m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m/libpython3.4m.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** unable to build python34 plugin ***
```

The alternative to use uwsgi without compiling it from the source is using pip3 install uwsgi, in this case the plugins are compiled in the folder **plugins/python/python_plugin.o** but can't find it. I'm using virtualenv for the project, the plugins compile must be on the root or inside the virtualenv enviroment in the lib folder ?

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using? If 14.04 you can use directly `apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python3` and just put as property `plugin=python3`on your app conf file.

Answer (score 5):

Old question but for future reference here is what I had done:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m/libpython3.4m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; **recompile with -fPIC**

This line implies that you need a python build with the flag: `-fPIC`, so I uninstalled the python version and rebuild with this flag on.

Export the flag before build like this:

```
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fPIC"
```

alternatively if you are using **pyenv**

```
env PYTHON_CFLAGS=-fPIC pyenv install 3.5.x
```

Now using this python, you can compile a python plugin:

```
python uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/python core python35
```