# uWSGI: implicit plugin requested nolang

Tags: python-3.x, uwsgi, pyenv

### Problem

We are using different Python versions with uWSGI since a few days. We managed to make it work. (The websites are running again.) But we get an error in our logs (`systemctl status uwsgi-emperor.service`):

```
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/uwsgi/uwsgi-emperor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-03-08 06:55:08 CET; 8min ago
  Process: 28501 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi_nolang --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini --emperor-pidfile /run/uwsgi/emperor.pid --plugins-dir /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins (code=exited, st
  Process: 28497 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown www-data:root /run/uwsgi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 28505 (uwsgi_nolang)
   Status: "The Emperor is governing 5 vassals"
    Tasks: 19 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 586.2M
      CPU: 1min 1.165s
   CGroup: /system.slice/uwsgi-emperor.service
           ├─28504 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi_nolang --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini --emperor-pidfile /run/uwsgi/emperor.pid --plugins-dir /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins
           ├─28505 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi_nolang --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini --emperor-pidfile /run/uwsgi/emperor.pid --plugins-dir /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins
           ├─28506 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi_nolang --ini /etc/uwsgi/vassals/site1.ini --include /etc/uwsgi/vassals-common.ini
           ...

systemd[1]: Starting uWSGI Emperor service...
uwsgi_nolang[28501]: [uwsgi] implicit plugin requested nolang
uwsgi_nolang[28501]: open("./nolang_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3724]
uwsgi_nolang[28501]: !!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./nolang_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
uwsgi_nolang[28501]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
```

I couldn't find a `nolang_plugin.so` anywhere. If you google for it, you get a hand full results only that didn't help.

I also checked that we don't require a `plugin = nolang` or something similar in our config files. (But in the logs it says that this plugin is requested implicit anyway.)

### Installation

Our system Python version is 3.5. I've installed Python 3.6 with pyenv: `env CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.6.8`. The `--enable-shared` is necessary to be able to build a uWSGI plugin with it. (Should I have installed it with `env PYTHON_CFLAGS=-fPIC pyenv install 3.6.8` instead as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38863007/2704544) says? Because the error message told me to re-compile Python with these flags but I didn't know about `PYTHON_CFLAGS` back then.)

Then we followed [these official instructions](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#bonus-multiple-python-versions-for-the-same-uwsgi-binary) to compile uWSGI and the plugins for Python 3.5 and 3.6.

I.e. compile uWSGI with `make PROFILE=nolang` and then build the plugins:

```sh
./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python35"
pyenv local 3.6.8
./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python36"
```

(We renamed the compiled `uwsgi` executable to `uwsgi_nolang`.)

### Environment

- Debian 4.9.130-2
- pyenv 1.2.9
- uWSGI 2.0.18
- nginx